# How to use machine learning algorithm for different input data?

Tags: machine-learning

Yes, my title is "How to use a machine learning algorithm for different input data?",
For example, we have an algorithm called "Email spams detector". Okay, so how to apply the algorithm for 1M users with different input data? because each user creates its own data. So instead of training 1M for every single user. Do we have any method to train once for different input data?

**To answer what do I mean by different input data:**

For example,
I have a time series data collected from a server called "Server A", the data consists of attributes like (CPU level, ram level, protocol...). Next, I put the data collected from Server A to "model X" to predict the server's usage.
Now I have a data center with hundreds of servers. Are there any ways to train these hundreds of servers' data once with the same model (model X)? Of course, I don't want to train hundreds of times with model X to get the prediction.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any ways to train these hundreds of servers' data once with the same model (model X)?

**Sure!** You can use Spark streaming for ingesting your time series  data from different servers/sources and Spark MLlib for processing data to train the same model (model X) stored in HDFS.

This [blog](https://blog.clairvoyantsoft.com/machine-learning-with-spark-streaming-281b2d1e4fd5) would be useful for your understanding

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I am looking for. I am looking for a method in multi-task learning which helps me train N input and get N output simultaneously after using a few hidden layers, for example.